# Menu Driven Program 1

Tags: java

I Need to write a menu driven program to allow the user to input two polynomials and then provide the user with a menu of options, I have already written the part of the code to input two polynomials... But i am struggling with the menu of options... the first option on the menu is to "evaluate the first polynimal at a value of x specified by the user". Here is my code so far :`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Polynomial2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, coef, x, deg, count = 2;
        double total = 0.0, result;
        char opt;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter Degree");
            deg = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter x");
            x = sc.nextInt();

            for (i = 0; i <= deg; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter Coefficent for " + i);
                coef = sc.nextInt();
                total = total + coef * Math.pow(x, i);
            }
            count--;
        } while (count > 0);
        System.out.println("Total=" + total);

        {
            coef = sc.nextInt();
            result = sc.nextDouble();
            opt = sc.next().charAt(0);

            switch (opt) {
                case 'a':
                    result = total + coef * Math.pow(x, i);
                    System.out.println("Evalute Polynomial 1 at x");
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    result = total + coef * Math.pow(x, i);
                    System.out.println("Evaluate Polynomial 2 at x");
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    result = total + total;
                    System.out.println("Add Polynomial 1 and 2");
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    result = total - total;
                    System.out.println("Subtract Polynomial 1 from Polynomial 2");
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    result = total - total;
                    System.out.println("Subtract Polynomial 2 from Polynomial 1");
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    result = total * x;
                    System.out.println("Multiply Polynomial 1 by a constant");
                    break;
                case 'g':
                    result = total * x;
                    System.out.println("Multiple Polynomial 2 by a constant");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Answer (score 0):

This is incoherent as a menu. To set up a basic menu program you need to give the user a print out of the Menu options and then use your scanner to receive their menu selection, then do an action based on that. *Trying* to guess what you need your menu to do from your code, I would do something like the following:

```
String menuPrompt = "Please select from the following options:\n\n" +
    "a - Evaluate Polynomial 1 at x\n" +
    "b - Evaluate Polynomial 2 at x\n" +
    "c - Add Polynomial 1 and 2\n" +
    "d - Subtract Polynomial 1 from Polynomial 2\n" +
    "e - Subtract Polynomial 2 from Polynomial 1\n" +
    "f - Multiply Polynomial 1 by a constant\n" +
    "g - Multiple Polynomial 2 by a constant\n\n" +
    "Enter selection: ";

System.out.print(menuPrompt);
char opt = sc.nextChar();

switch(opt) {
    case 'a':
        result = total + coef * Math.pow(x, i);
        break;
    case 'b':
    //...etc...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for